# How to add alternate icon for task view in android?

Tags: android

So I was roaming around when I saw that there Facebook had different icon when  viewing Running Tasks in API 26.

How can I do this with my app?

Facebook's  actual icon has opposite colors of this. ***Any help would be deeply appreciated!***

[image]

Comment: Savings is my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `use setTaskDescription()`.

quote from "**busy coder guide for android development**"

> For Android 5.0+, setTaskDescription() allows you to associate an
>   ActivityManager.TaskDescription instance with your task. Here you can provide
>   values that help drive what the task looks like on the overview screen. Specifically,
>   you can provide the icon, title, and background color to use for the title bar over
>   your thumbnail on the overview screen.

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      setTaskDescription(
          new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(
              title,  //or null for default title
              R.drawable.task_icon,
              color // or null for default color                    
      )  
  }
```

Comment: inside `onCreate()`